# Как объединить 1D массив с 2D массивом

Tags: python

Пример:

```
A = ['a', 'b']
B = [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

Результат:

```
C = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['b', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A
['a', 'b']
>>> B
[[1, 2], [4, 5]]
>>> [[A[i], j] for i in range(len(A)) for j in B[i]]
[['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['b', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b']
b = [[1, 2], [4, 5]]

[[r, sc] for r, c in zip(a, b) for sc in c]
```